# QBasic in Dosbox : MS-DOS interrupt says there's no mouse

Tags: dosbox, qbasic

I'm using QBASIC version **QB45**

I'm using the classic code snippet to get the state of the mouse, through a system interrupt :

```
 STATIC Regs as RegType
 Regs.ax = &H0
 CALL INTERRUPT(&H33, Regs, Regs)

IF Regs.ax = &HFFFF THEN
    PRINT "ooops! No Mouse!"
    SYSTEM
ENDIF
```

When I run the program, it does fail with "oooops! No mouse!"

I know that there *is* a mouse and that MS-DOS is not bothered by DosBox, as **the mouse does work in the QBASIC graphical interface and I'm using it**. It's only *inside* my program that it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There were two distinct issues:

1. There was an issue with the `STATIC` . I thought it meant "local variable2 in QBASIC. So I removed it.
2. despite Reg.ax being negative, the mouse still works. I can read CX, DX to get the mouse position and BX to get the buttons status.

Which leads to the core issue : **Why does Dosbox say that there's no mouse available** when I can display it and show it?

Maybe I simply misunderstand the meaning of "negative AX"; maybe it just means "no driver" but the mouse still works magically. For example, this page does not mention a possible negative result : https://www.equestionanswers.com/c/c-int33-mouse-service.php

Dosbox has an `int33=false` setting, maybe it has something to do with it. See  https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x/issues/1315

I've updated my code to use **INTERRUPTX** instead of INTERRUPT:

```
 STATIC Regs as RegTypeX
 Regs.ax = &H0
 CALL INTERRUPTX(&H33, Regs, Regs)

'IF Regs.ax = &HFFFF THEN
'    PRINT "ooops! No Mouse!"
'    SYSTEM
'ENDIF

VAR SHARED MOUSEX = Regs.CX
VAR SHARED MOUSEY = regs.DX
```